# Issue in React native Version 0.60 ->null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, file-not-found

I'm using react-native-gesture-handler within react-navigation and getting this error

null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction')

Workspace file is automatically created with new React native version(0.60). And there is no libraries under libraries folder in Xcode project.

I created new project in react native and new project created with react-native version 0.60 automatically. Then I installed following dependencies

npm install —save react-navigation
npm install —save react-native-gesture-handler
After installing I am getting runtime error

null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction')

I also tried to manually link react-native-gesture-handler dependencies with following steps

Right Click Libraries "Add Files to Project"
/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handlers/ios/RNGestureHandler.xcodeproj
Go to build phases and add libRNGestureHandler.a
Run
After that I am getting following errors

->  File not found
->  File not found

Any suggestion for me to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try using `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`?
For me the solution was:

1) `react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`

2) `cd ios`

3) `pod install`

as now, pod is installed automatically into the project with react-native 0.60

Answer (score 4):

If you use RN > 0.60 you don't have to link react-native-gesture-handler manually as it supports autolinking.

**For iOS**

```
cd ios && pod install
```

For further info see [issue #671](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/issues/671#issuecomment-508903588)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to link react-native-gesture-handler then fixed this error

try this command for link gesture-handler pluggin

> react-native link react-native-gesture-handler